# Get id's of people that are using your facebook app at this moment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

How can I get a list of all the people that are using my Facebook app at this moment?
Is that even possible? 
I need it in order to compare with user's friends, so the users would know if one of their friends playing the game right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to store and surface this information in your own system. There is no Facebook API or method that returns this information.

Comment: Great answer.  You should be tracking who is in your game and store it in a session var or other data store.